# Ruby script to perform ntohl on STDIN

Tags: ruby, scripting

I need to create a script that converts a 4 byte input into its reversed form. I imagine the basic algorithm is something like

1. Read input from STDIN
2. Convert to byte array
3. Reverse the array
4. Write bytes on STDOUT

Any help greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
STDIN.read(4).unpack('C*').reverse.pack('C*')
```

It reads four bytes from `STDIN`, unpacks the string as a list of 8 bit unsigned integers, reverses the list and then packs it back as 8 bit unsigned integers.

Answer (score 0):

@Theo answered the steps listed in your question, but the answer assumes that your host is not the same order as the network order.  To be safe, a simpler, but effective solution is:

```
STDIN.read(4).unpack("N")[0]
```

since that will transform the data you've read from network order to host order regardless of whether they are the same or different.  Also, it communicates intent better **and** is less steps than the `pack`/`reverse`/`unpack` solution.